# Importing provable in remix ide

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to learn solidity on the online ide. I am trying to use Provable within the ide and I have activated the plugin. I thought maybe that could just inherit 'usingProvable' off the bat to my contract but the ide could not find the identifier. I tried importing the plugin from github but still is not able to find it. If anything it creates a bigger problem because the ide does not find any of the openzepplin files when I try to import the package. How would I accomplish this on the online ide?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;



import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/utils/Counters.sol";
import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI.sol";



contract Neuron is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

constructor() ERC721("Neuron", "Neuron") {}

// function make_call() public {
//     provable_query("URL","https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT");
// }



function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "http://api.Neuron.com/tokens/";
}

function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
}

// The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
}
```

this is a simple premade contract on remix and had not changed anything yet.  I had commented out the function for testing a query call.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: sorry about that. code added

Answer (score 0):

`provable_api` is a bit outdated. The file you import is a symlink to `provableAPI_0.4.25.sol` which allows compiler versions `>= 0.4.22 < 0.5`, while your imported OpenZeppelin contracts require `^0.8.0`.

- You can find a matching version
- You can copy the provable_api contract locally in Remix IDE and use a relative path and try using a higher compiler version

PS. I think Remix IDE is having trouble with symbolic links. You can see the problem easier if you import the library like this:

```
import "github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/provableAPI_0.5.sol";
```